# Type hint for "hashable"

Tags: python, type-hinting

Sometimes an argument to a function I write can be of any type as long as it is a [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) - for instance, because my function adds it to a set or uses it as a dictionary key.

Is there a way to type-hint this fact using the PEP 484 type hints introduced in Python 3.5? The [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module doesn't seem to include a hashable type, but is there some other way?

Comment: I was just going to post the exact same answer. If an ABC will do, `typing` re-exports it. There is `typing.Generator` and `typing.Sized` too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `typing` module *does* in fact contain a [`Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Hashable) type (now documented). It's an alias for [`collections.abc.Hashable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Hashable).

```
>>> import typing
>>> typing.Hashable
<class 'collections.abc.Hashable'>
```

Comment: I think that's the case becaus hashable doesn't need to be generic so there is no gain in "reimplementing" it in `typing` whereas a list (or collection) needs the generic information for type safety.